# Segmentation Fault, pointer issue?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm pretty new to C coding, and pointers are something I'm having a lot of trouble with. I'm trying to write a program that takes in 2 pointers as parameters, adds the value of the first to the second, then returns the value of the first. What I've written is this:

```
int foo(int *g, int *h)
{ 
    int a;
    a = *g; 
    *h += a;
    return a; 
}
```

However, I am getting a segmentation fault error using an online compiler. I read that these are caused by rogue pointers, but I'm not sure where the error is. Can someone help?

EDIT:
I'm calling this function this way:

```
    main()
{
   int* x;
   *x = 3;
   int* y;
   *y = 4;
   int z = foo(x, y);
   printf("%d", z);
}
```

I thought that was the way to declare a pointer, and that using (*) to dereference it was how to assign it a value. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Make sure everything is right before the call.

Comment: How are you calling this function? Show us a short full example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `main` you have to allocate spaces for `x` and `y` before you can use it. If `x` and `y` are not allocated spaces, they point to arbitrary memory locations. If they are outside of your program segment, you will get a segmentation fault.

```
main()
{
   int* x=malloc(sizeof(int));
   *x = 3;
   int* y=malloc(sizeof(int));
   *y = 4;
   int z = fun(x, y);
   printf("%d", z);
}
```

Or like this:

```
main()
{
   int x=3,y=4;
   int z = fun(&x, &y);
   printf("%d", z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that it was a problem with the foo code, but it turns out it was, in fact, how I was declaring the variables. Your second solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause a segfault because you are dereferencing a pointer that has not been initialized.

```
 int *x;    // declares pointer X
 *x = 3;    // seg fault here because x contains garbage and points certainly to 
            // invalid memory
```